setXIncludeAware is not supported on JAXP implementation
Could you please help to solve the issue "setXIncludeAware is not supported on this JAXP implementation or earlier: class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl"
Java version used in server : 1.8.0_361
JVM rumtime version : 8.1.092 11.0.18+000
and the project is build using : saxon-he-12.5.jar
code snippet:
public class PositionalXMLReader {
    final static String LINE_NUMBER_KEY_NAME = "lineNumber";
    final static String END_LINE_NUMBER_KEY_NAME = "endLineNumber";

    public static Document readXML(final InputStream is) throws IOException, SAXException {
        final Document doc;
        SAXParser parser;
        try {
            final SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            
            
            factory.setXIncludeAware(true);
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            
            
            final DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            final DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        } catch (final ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't create SAX parser / DOM builder.", e);
        }

Code execution on server without the following error :
"Details: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException;  setXIncludeAware is not supported on this JAXP implementation or earlier: class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl, UnsupportedOperationException:  setXIncludeAware is not supported on this JAXP implementation or earlier: class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl"

Why is that tagged as saxon if you simply use Java JAXP APIs for XML parsing? Saxon is an XSLT processor. And why do you need both DOM and SAX in the same function?

Thanks for responding. more than 5tags were not allowed, had to remove jaxp. there was s a xslt called from the same java code. i'm more worried about these 2 lines.             factory.setXIncludeAware(true);
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

Do you use or reference a specific Xerces version? The documentation of the latest version https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xinclude.html suggests you can use e.g. SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); spf.setNamespaceAware(true); spf.setXIncludeAware(true);

Looks like you're picking up the Apache version of Xerces rather than the JDK version, and it's possible you're picking up a rather old version. Check what's on your classpath.
And frankly, using the JAXP methods like SAXParserFactory.newInstance() is thoroughly dangerous. It means you'll pick up whatever implementation is lying around on the classpath at the time the program runs, which might be quite different from any implementation that you tested your code against.
I used to recommend using Apache Xerces in preference to the JDK version because it was better maintained, the JDK version had some serious bugs. That situation is now reversed, and the JDK version is to be preferred.

Hi Michael,
saxon9he.jar is used to build the project.

That's irrelevant. Saxon isn't involved here: it's your Java code deciding what XML parser to load.

sorry for the misunderstanding. below imports in the code used for parser, as you mentioned, its from javax package & not from the apache. and after applying sapjavm_8 as an alternate JRE also the error remains same!
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory; javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;

also please check the classpath -








JAXP defines interfaces, not implementations of those interfaces. The whole point of SAXParserFactory.newInstance() is that it will give you whatever XML parser it finds on the classpath, whether you have static imports for it or not. The fact that the error message refers to org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl makes it clear you have some version of Apache Xerces on the classpath. I don't know Eclipse so I can't relate that to your Eclipse configuration files.
